# Isolating host machine from external network

Tags: network, linux, virtualization

How to prevent a host machine from sending/receiving packets with the following network configuration:

`eth0` - physical NIC :: not configured;

`tun0` - virtual NIC for VM which role is the gateway for other VMs :: auto configured (`dhcp`), has Internet access, receives ip from the router (`192.168.1.1/24`);

`tun1` - virtual NIC, the gateway for other VMs :: `10.0.2.1/24`, `dhcpd`, iptables with `NAT` masquerading 10.0.2.0/24 through tun0 (which is `eth0` in the guest VM)

`bridge0` - bridge that includes `eth0` and `tun0` :: not configured

`bridge1` - bridge that includes all VMs virtual NICs (tun{1...}) :: auto configured, receives ip from the gateway's VM dhcpd (`10.0.2.1`), but default route through `10.0.2.1` is deleted.

I want to completely isolate my host machine from the external network (Internet in my case). And I need to access VMs network `10.0.2.0/24`. So the route table on the host machine looks like:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br1
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
127.0.0.0       127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 lo
```

But there is one VM that is the gateway to Internet for other VMs, but not for the host (which is part of 10.0.2.0/24 network). I'm interested if deleting the default gw is sufficient or some smart software running in user-space can detect that `10.0.2.1` is the gateway to Internet and Linux kernel allows to route to unknown hosts through that.

Comment: Is a test VLAN option available to you?

Answer (score 1):

on IP layer the host machine will not receive nor transmit anything. However, on layer 2 and below it will see all traffic. What is your real objective?

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish this with a VLAN.  There's a good explanation of VLANS on the serverfault.com site here:

[How to set up VLAN network](https://serverfault.com/questions/430309/how-to-set-up-vlan-network)